# Python Classes : How to add a custom method to an existing object (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, oop

I would like to build a data viewer, leveraging off EXCEL, for viewing the contents of a pandas `DataFrame`.  A simple working example (as a function) is below.  However, rather than call this as `view(df,10)`, I would like to call this as a method `df.view(10)`, similar to how one would use `head`, eg `df.head(10)`.

I am new to python `classes`. All the examples on the internet are of defining a new object and developing classes for that new object.  But I think I need to add a method to an existing pandas `DataFrame`.  I would like this new method to be stored in my own private repository that I can then import, eg `from brb import *`, and be able to use this on any arbitrary `DataFrame`.

Is this possible to do?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xl


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)*10,
    'year': tuple(np.arange(2011,2021))*10,
    'a': np.random.choice(range(2),100),
    'b': np.random.choice(range(100),100),
})


def view(df,NObs=None):
    book = xl.Book()
    book.sheets[0].range("A1").value = df[:NObs]


#  What I have:
view(df,10)   

#  What I want:
df.view(10)
```

Comment: You can just monkey patch it.  i.e `pd.DataFrame.view = view`, and then all dataframes created after executing this line can be called with `df.view(10)`.  A cleaner solution would be to define accessor objects (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#registering-custom-accessors) but I'd suggest this is too much if you're only just starting with classes.

Comment: Thank you!  This monkey patching thing works.  I will investigate the cleaner solution later once I have learnt more, but I appreciate the link as it gives me something to go on down the track.  I did try to upvote your comment, but have messed that up and can't now.  Sorry about that.  I appreciate the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own class like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xl


class MyDataFrame:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    def view(self, NObs=None):
        book = xl.Book()
        book.sheets[0].range("A1").value = self.df[:NObs]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = MyDataFrame(
        {
            "id": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) * 10,
            "year": tuple(np.arange(2011, 2021)) * 10,
            "a": np.random.choice(range(2), 100),
            "b": np.random.choice(range(100), 100),
        }
    )
    df.view(10)
```

And then run the script directly or import `MyDataFrame` elsewhere.

Or you could even add your own method to Pandas objects and run it "natively", like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xl
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject


def view(df, NObs=None):
    book = xl.Book()
    book.sheets[0].range("A1").value = df[:NObs]


PandasObject.view = view


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "id": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) * 10,
            "year": tuple(np.arange(2011, 2021)) * 10,
            "a": np.random.choice(range(2), 100),
            "b": np.random.choice(range(100), 100),
        }
    )
    df.view(10)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I'm back at my computer. Would this allow me to eventually put it in a module called say brb, then I would do from brb import * and I could use df.view() then? Apologies, don't know enough about this yet...

Comment: Actually. Looking again at the code. Do I have to set each new data frame, df =  MyDataFrame? So if won't work out of the box on a new pandas dataframe until I set that equal to MyDataFrame?

Comment: Got it, see my updated answer.

Comment: That is perfect, I really appreciate the help.  Thank you!